# Trying to create a wrapper for jQuery methods

Tags: javascript, methods, prototype, wrapper

I wish to create a wrapper for each and every method in jQuery that will for example output a console.log each time the method is called.
Not sure what I am missing.

Started with wrapping a single method (addClass)
like so:

```
_addClass=jQuery.prototype.addClass;
jQuery.prototype.addClass = function () {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 0);
    console.log('addClass arguments',args);
    return _addClass.apply(this, args);
};
$('body').addClass('blue')
```

Which worked pretty well for me.
Next I try to iterate over all of the jQuery methods, which I am having difficulty with:

```
function wrapClass (o)
{
    for (var m in o.prototype)
    {
        if (typeof(o.prototype[m]) === "function")
        {
             console.log('wrapping ',m);
             var _temp=o.prototype[m];
             o.prototype[m] = function () {
                var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 0);
                console.log(m+' arguments',args);
                return _temp.apply(this, args);
            };
        }
    }
};
wrapClass(jQuery);
```

This produces a TypeError
"this.off is not a function"

Also tried (per Barni's comment) to create a closure like so:

```
function wrapClass (o)
{
    for (var m in o.prototype)
    {
        if (typeof(o.prototype[m]) === "function")
        {
            (function(){
                var _temp=o.prototype[m];
                console.log('wrapping ',m,typeof(_temp));
                        o.prototype[m] = function () {
                        var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 0);
                        console.log(m+' arguments',args);
                        return _temp.apply(this, args);
                };
            })(m);
        }
    }
};
wrapClass(jQuery);
$('body').addClass('blue');
```

But now I get the following output and error:

```
undelegate arguments ["body", undefined]
undelegate arguments ["body"]
undelegate arguments [Array[0]]
undelegate arguments []
undelegate arguments [undefined, undefined]
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).addClass is not a function
```

Thank you

Comment: you could try to log `o.prototype[m]` as well as `m` to see which type `addClass` is. Maybe it not a function type, but something else that you need to consider?

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with variable *_temp*. You create this variable in scope of function *wrapClass*, so you overwrite it in every loop iteration. At the end you have always the last jQuery method there (which is undelegate probably).
I didn't analized the whole case but after your loop you always invoke last method, no mather what jQuery function you call.

Comment: Thanks Barni. I suspected something like this, so I need to create an enclosure?